# How to append dataframes based on overlapping date values?

Tags: r, merge, append, overlapping

I'm trying to combine two large data frames containing temperature data from a several data loggers. The data loggers and column names are the same in each data frame. One data frame contains values which are more recent than the other data frame.

The data basically looks like this:

```
date.time           date         temp1    temp2   
2011-08-22 19:00    2011-08-22   11.265   5.562   
2011-08-22 20:00    2011-08-22   11.254   6.541   
2011-08-22 22:00    2011-08-22   12.256   5.456   
2011-08-22 23:00    2011-08-22   13.568   15.265  

date.time<-c("2011-08-22 19:00", "2011-08-22 20:00", "2011-08-22 22:00","2011-08-22 23:00")
date<-c("2011-08-22","2011-08-22","2011-08-22","2011-08-22")
temp1<-c(11.265,11.254,12.256,13.568)
temp2<-c(5.562,6.541,5.456,15.265)
df_old<-data.frame(date.time,date,temp1,temp2)
```

And:

```
date.time           date         temp1    temp2   temp3   
2011-08-22 22:00    2011-08-22   12.256   5.456   24.598  
2011-08-22 23:00    2011-08-22   13.568   15.265  11.265  
2011-08-22 24:00    2011-08-22   11.275   5.563   25.295  
2011-08-23 00:00    2011-08-23   11.254   6.544   24.689  

date.time<-c("2011-08-22 22:00", "2011-08-22 23:00", "2011-08-22 24:00","2011-08-23 00:00")
date<-c("2011-08-22","2011-08-22","2011-08-22","2011-08-23")
temp1<-c(12.256,13.568,11.275,11.254)
temp2<-c(5.456,15.265,5.563,6.544)
temp3<-c(24.598,11.265,25.295,24.689)
df_new<-data.frame(date.time,date,temp1,temp2,temp3)
```

I want to join these together lengthwise based on the shared values in the date.time column to get:

```
date.time           date         temp1    temp2   temp3   
2011-08-21 19:00    2011-08-22   11.265   5.562   NA
2011-08-21 20:00    2011-08-22   11.254   6.541   NA
2011-08-21 22:00    2011-08-22   12.256   5.456   24.598  
2011-08-21 23:00    2011-08-22   13.568   15.265  11.265  
2011-08-21 24:00    2011-08-22   11.275   5.563   25.295  
2011-08-21 00:00    2011-08-23   11.254   6.544   24.689
```

I have tried just appending one to the other using rbind.fill.

```
df_all<-rbind.fill(df_old, df_new)
```

This does account for the differing number of columns. However, it just adds the columns together one on-top of the other instead of putting rows with shared values in the date.time column together.

I've tried looking for how to do this but have only found how to merge data frames side-by-side based on values in a shared column but not how to merge them top-to-bottom when there are overlapping values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're describing is a merge:

```
merge(df_old,df_new,by=c("date.time","date","temp1","temp2"),all=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
         date.time       date  temp1  temp2  temp3
1 2011-08-22 19:00 2011-08-22 11.265  5.562     NA
2 2011-08-22 20:00 2011-08-22 11.254  6.541     NA
3 2011-08-22 22:00 2011-08-22 12.256  5.456 24.598
4 2011-08-22 23:00 2011-08-22 13.568 15.265 11.265
5 2011-08-22 24:00 2011-08-22 11.275  5.563 25.295
6 2011-08-23 00:00 2011-08-23 11.254  6.544 24.689
```

**Edit:**

As @eipi10 suggested, another option to do the same is:

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df_old, df_new)
```

Comment: Also `library(dplyr); full_join(df_old, df_new)`.